# How to achieve tabbed code blocks in Gatsby and Asciidoctor.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm using Gatsby and Asciidoctor.js to develop a documentation web site,
I need to fetch same code samples for multiple languages (e.g. same code for both JAVA and Kotlin) and represent them as tabbed code blocks.
I have found [this extension](https://github.com/bmuschko/asciidoctorj-tabbed-code-extension), but this is for AsciidoctorJ,
Is there any way that I can achieve this on Asciidocor.js or some how use mentioned Java plugin in Asciidoctor.js?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at https://gitlab.com/antora/antora-asciidoctor-extensions/-/tree/main/tabs-block which basically does the same.

You will have to include both `behavior.js` and `style.css` in your HTML page.